# Should a list of multiple singular nouns be modified by a plural or singular adjective?

Tags: adjetivos, sustantivos, plurales

Whenever I have a list of multiple singular nouns in Spanish, I don't know if the modifying adjective should be singular or plural (update: note that I want this one adjective to modify both preceding nouns).

Example:

> El médico tiene la autoridad para restringir la libertad de un paciente con tal de que sea necesario para dar **el cuidado médico y tratamiento adecuado**.

Or should it be **el cuidado médico y tratamiento adecuados** or something else?

Can someone please help me identify the correct way to do it, and why?

Update:

A parallel to this question that makes me think of it is this example with nouns and verbs: **La ropa y el equipaje del paciente serán devueltos.**  Notice you have two singular nouns followed by a verb conjugated in the third person plural.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends.

If you mean that both nouns have the same property, then the adjective is plural.

> [cuidado médico **adecuado**] + [tratamiento **adecuado**] = cuidado médico y tratamiento **adecuados**

On the other hand, if the property pertains only to the noun with which it's attached, then the adjective is singular.

> [cuidado médico] + [tratamiento adecuado] = cuidado médico y tratamiento **adecuado**

In the sentence that you give us by example it's really difficult to distinguish one meaning from the other, so I would say both forms are fine.

But sometimes the grammatical difference implies a critical difference in reality:

> Una esfera y un cubo **blanco**. (Here the sphere is not necessarily white.)
>
> Una esfera y un cubo **blancos**. (The sphere is white).

Comment: Qué útiles son los paréntesis matemáticos para estas situaciones. Así sería más fácil ver la diferencia entre _(una esfera) y (un cubo blanco)_ y _(una esfera y un cubo) blancos_.

Comment: I would add that besides number, there's also gender agreement. If all the noun phrases are feminine, the adjective will be feminine; if any of them is masculine, the adjective will be masculine.